# $k[X_1,...,X_n]$ is Cohen-Macaulay (CM) ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

It is normal if we know the ring $k[X_1,...,X_n]$ is Cohen-Macaulay (CM) ring by the definition which is that the ring has unmixed condition.

However, I got stuck when I try to prove that ring is CM ring by this definition: $R$ is a CM ring if the localization of $R$ at $P$, $R_{P}$ is a CM local ring (I suppose that this means $R_{P}$ is an $R$-module whence $\operatorname{depth}R_{P}=\dim R_{P}=\operatorname{ht}P$).

It is very grateful to me if you help me solve it by this definition. Thanks you in advance.

Comment: When you want to prove a well known fact of $k[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]$ by hand, Noether-Normalization is almost always your friend. This allows you to reduce to the trivial case $P=(x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_m)$ for some $m \leq n$.

Comment: How could it suffice to show the case $P=(x_{1},..,x_{m})$? I think you use the one : $R_{P}$ is CM iff $R_{M}$ is CM with $M$ is a maximal ideal.

If so, I suppose that you used the unmixed condition already. However, I know the Noether-Normalization $dim P=m$ with $P$ as the ideal you wrote. Now, we $(x_{1},..,x_{m})$ is a regular sequence in $P$ then $depth R_{P}\ge depth P \ge m =dim P =dim R_{P} \ge depth R_{P}$ then we have done right?

Answer (score 1):

Let me elaborate on my brief comment.

Let $P$ be a prime ideal of height $d$ in $R=k[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]$. Then Noether normalization (as in *Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra, Theorem 13.3*) in particular tells us that there is a polynomial ring $S=k[t_1, \dotsc, t_n] \subset R$ such that $P \cap S = (t_1, \dotsc, t_d)$.

In particular $P$ contains the regular sequence $t_1, \dotsc, t_d$ of length $d$, thus $R_P$ is Cohen-Macaulay.

The fact that $S \subset R$ is a finite ring extension is not even needed for our application.

Comment: Actually, I did not know we could take $d=dim P.$ I think we only have that it is the number generator of P. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry, but I still dont see why you have $P\cap S=(t_{1},..,t_{d})$. I think it is $(t_{d+1},..,t_{n})$

Comment: Actually (using notation of Eisenbud) it is $(t_{n-d+1}, \dotsc, t_n)$, but this is just a matter of numbering...

Comment: Sorry, it is still weird. The diagram $I_{1},..,I_{d}$ does not satisfy the condition $d_{1}>d_{2}>...$ I mean in this post we have $P\cap S=(t_{d+1},...,t_{n})$

Comment: I think your confusion arises, because you think that dimension = height. Actually it is codimension = height.

Comment: Taking $P$ is a prime ideal in $R $ with $  dim P=d$. You have $P\cap S=(t_{n-d+1},..,t_{n})$? I think it is $P\cap S=(t_{d+1},...,t_{n})$. I just wonder this one.

Comment: I am truly sorry, this file write dim $I_{i}=d_{i}$ but actually it must be codim $I_{i} =d_{i}$. That is so stupid mistake from me. So, thank you so much.